# How to store and call data from YAML file using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, yaml

I'm writing features and step definitions using Cucumber and Capybara, I want to store user credentials in a YAML file.

My question is if I have a cred.yml file in my support/config.yml, and I load the file in my env.rb (`CONFIG = YAML.load_file("/config/config.yml")`), will all of the information be accessible? If so how will I access/call user1 from env_1 for example?

Or if I want to only load one/multiple select environment at a time, how would I do that? And how would I access/call the different users?

Something like this:
`CONFIG = YAML.load_file("/config/config.yml")[ENV]`?

config.yml file contents:

`env_1:`

```
 `user1: admin`
 `password1: password`
 `user2: teacher`
 `password2: password`
```

`env_2:`

```
 `user: student`
 `password: password`
 `user2: assistant`
 `password2: password`
```

Comment: why don't you just try an see what happens?

Answer (score 4):

`YAML::load_file` returns a nested hash:

```
require 'yaml'
config = YAML.load_file("config.yml") #=> {"env_1"=>{"user1"=>"admin", "password1"=>"password", "user2"=>"teacher", "password2"=>"password"}, "env_2"=>{"user"=>"student", "password"=>"password", "user2"=>"assistant", "password2"=>"password"}}
```

You can access `env_1` with:

```
config["env_1"] #=> {"user1"=>"admin", "password1"=>"password", "user2"=>"teacher", "password2"=>"password"}
```

And its values with:

```
config["env_1"]["user1"] #=> "admin"
config["env_1"]["user2"] #=> "teacher"
```

Accessing `env_2` works accordingly:

```
config["env_2"]["user"]  #=> "student"
```

Assuming your `config.yml` looks like this:

```
env_1:
  user1: admin
  password1: password
  user2: teacher
  password2: password
env_2:
  user: student
  password: password
  user2: assistant
  password2: password
```

Comment: Just to add on, if you're using Rails, it might be helpful to create your config with indifferent access, ie `config = YAML.load("config.yml").with_indifferent_access`